# How to compare two lists in lisp that are not exactly the same in length or structure?

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp

I have these two lists:

```
'(and 1 (or a b))
'( (a 0)(b 1) )
```

I am new to lisp, and I am finding it very hard to figure out how to compare these two lists. I am thinking of creating a comparison function, but I don't know how to compare them one by one as in lisp values aren't returned until the expression is evaluated. Since they aren't the same structure either, I can't assume they will be the same, structurally at least. Any explanation how this works?

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to say why I am comparing. The second list is to suppose to bind the number to everywhere where those variables exists in the first list. So the resulting first list should be:

```
'(and 1(or 0 1))
```

Comment: If you don't know how to specify the structure of the solution, you won't be able to write the code. What should the result be for the above two lists if you manually compare them? The built in EQUAL function will return NIL because they are different lists.

Comment: I just added it, sorry for not adding it at first

Comment: What is the actual homework question?

Comment: I see. Well, that is not comparing; that is substitution! You are supposed to instantiate the variables specified in the second list inside the first list.  There is a SUBLIS function in CL which does this.

Comment: Oh I understand that! I was just trying to do it on my own to understand the lisp control structures. But its really hard to visualize how this would work. I looked into the function, but if I were to try and do it on my own, how would I be able to do it?

Comment: One way is to make a function which can substitute a single variable everywhere in a tree structure. Then iterate over the variables and filter the list for each variable. Another way is to walk the tree structure once, and whenever a symbol is seen, try to substitute the value. These processes are naturally recursive. If you have a cons C, you can compute the substitute of (car C) and of (cdr C) and then cons these two together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Built in:

```
$ clisp -q
[1]> (sublis '((a . 0) (b . 1)) '(and 1 (or a b)))
(AND 1 (OR 0 1))
[2]>
```

So the homework reduces to making a wrapper for SUBLIS which accepts the bindings in the form ((a 0) (b 1)) rather than ((a . 0) (b . 1)).

Clue:

```
(loop for (x y) in vars collecting (cons x y))
```

Comment: I'm not sure that a SUBLIS based solution will be accepted as homework. But it's the teacher's fault. Making students implement trivial functions is appropriate in teaching Scheme, not Lisp. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
;;; Look up a var like A a list like ((A 0) (B 1))
;;; and retrieve the (A 0). Or nil if not found.
(defun lookup-var (var bindings)
  (find var bindings :key #'first))

;;; The homework
(defun subst-vars (tree bindings)
  (cond
    ;; if the tree is a cons cell, then substitute in the
    ;; car, substitute in the cdr, and combine the results by consing
    ;; a new cons! Easy!
    ((consp tree) (cons (subst-vars (car tree) bindings)
                        (subst-vars (cdr tree) bindings)))
    ;; Otherwise the tree must be an atom. See if the atom is
    ;; a var that we can substitute. If not, return the atom.
    (t (let ((binding (lookup-var tree bindings)))
         (if binding
           (second binding) ;; got a binding entry; return its value!
           tree)))))            ;; no deal, just return the original
```

Typed this right in the stackoverflow window and it ran with no edits. :)

This is quite inefficient though. Suppose that the variables do not occur in the tree at all. It makes a wasteful copy of the tree instead of just returning the tree. So that you do some work on this yourself, can you figure out a way to optimize it so that it avoids calling the cons function unnecessarily? Hint: check if the recursive calls to subst-vars just return the same object.